# looping through list of tuples with Python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples and I'm trying to loop through it accessing each one individually, not all at once.

```
results = [(1,'one',2,'two'),(3,'three',4,'four')]
```

I have this so far:

```
for item in (results):
    for i in (item):
        print(i)
```

But that gives me everything, how to I only access the first Tuple then the second separately? ex:

```
 1
one
2
two
```

then break

```
3
three
4
four
```

then so on...

Comment: Are you looking for `results[0]`?

Comment: Google "How to get the first element of a list" gogogogo

Comment: Avoid using parentheses around list in for loop they are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on first element of your list:

```
for item in results[0]:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
>> python loop.py 
1
one
2
two
```

Iterate on second element of your list:

```
for item in results[1]:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
>> python loop.py 
3
three
4
four
```

Access only the tuples:

```
for item in results:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
>> python loop.py 
(1, 'one', 2, 'two')
(3, 'three', 4, 'four')
```

EDIT:

Iterate both tuples and do something between them:

```
counter = 0
for tuple_var in results:
        if counter != 0:
            print("Only between iterations.")
        for element in tuple_var:
            print(element)
        counter += 1
```

Output:

```
>> python loop.py 
1
one
2
two
Only between iterations.
3
three
4
four
```

Comment: this is close to what I'm trying to achieve! thanks. I've updated my question to be al little more specific.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it can help you. Let me know if you think different thing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for printing only, you could write something like this if you wanted it on one line.

```py
results = [(1,'one',2,'two'),(3,'three',4,'four')]
print(*["{} - {} - {} - {}".format(*i) for i in results], sep = "\nNEXT ITEM\n")
```

You can adjust the formatting yourself.

The `*` is a splat operator and it unpacks the following list

`"{} - {} - {} - {}".format(*i)` uses the splat operator again to unpack `i` and formats it by filling in each of the curly braces with the elements in `i`.

`... for i in results` is a for-loop comprehension. `i` is each tuple in `results`.

The `sep` keyword in print is what will be printed in between each item. In this case, between each tuple.

The output is

```
1 - one - 2 - two
NEXT ITEM
3 - three - 4 - four
```